# Spring Cloud Data Flow - Http --> HttpClient (pass headers)

Tags: spring-cloud-dataflow

Assume a Spring Cloud Dataflow (SCDF) stream like

**http**|**httpclient**|**custom-app**|**log**

Given I invoke the stream from postman with headers: Content-Type and **Custom** header (e.g 'fileName')

What would be the approach to pass **all** the headers from '**http**' app to '**custom-app**' in above scenario in SCDF.

[Issue fix: to configure mapped-request-headers and headers-expression as shown here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uOy2T.jpg)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you need to use `mapped-request-headers` option in the `http` application as defined [here](https://github.com/spring-cloud-stream-app-starters/http/blob/master/spring-cloud-starter-stream-source-http/README.adoc).

Comment: Thank you, Illayaperumal. As shown in screenshot, setting the **mapped-request-headers** property in **Http** and **headers-expression** in **HTTPClient**  resolved the issue.